# Python: passing the script as a string to the interpreter

Tags: python, batch-file

Is there a way to run directly a script without saving it in an external ".py" file . I am trying to do something like this

```
python.exe  "print('hello world !')"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-c` flag.

```
python -c "print('hello world !')"
```